# How to properly use ca_file for self-signed certificates with Net::HTTP in ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, ssl, self-signed

I am trying to understand how to use the `ca_file` property of the `Net::HTTP` class to allow connections to hosts with self-signed certificates.

I have prepared a minimal example of my current approach. Check https://repl.it/repls/ElegantRaggedInstitutes or keep reading here:

I have used this command to get a hold of the certificate of https://self-signed.badssl.com

```sh
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect self-signed.badssl.com:443 < /dev/null
```

I have then stored the certificate in a local file and tried to execute the following snippet

```rb
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

http_conn = Net::HTTP.new('self-signed.badssl.com', 443)
http_conn.use_ssl = true
http_conn.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http_conn.ca_file = '/path/to/badssl.cert'
http_conn.start
```

I expected this to successfully open a connection, accepting the certificate. Instead, it gives me this error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)
```

I am surely doing something wrong, can you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the certificates got messed. Not sure if I executed the wrong command, copied from the wrong shell or maybe the certificate of self-signed.badssl.com just changed. The certificate that is included in the original repl is actually not self-signed but is signed by an untrusted intermediate CA that was not included in the chain (i.e. I did not add it to the ca_file).

I have verified that by running the command

```
openssl x509 -text -in /path/to/badssl.crt
```

and observing the oputput

```
...
        Serial Number:
            cd:bc:5a:4a:ec:97:67:b1
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = BadSSL, CN = BadSSL Intermediate Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug  8 21:17:05 2016 GMT
            Not After : Aug  8 21:17:05 2018 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = BadSSL Fallback. Unknown subdomain or no SNI., CN = badssl-fallback-unknown-subdomain-or-no-sni
...
```

Today I grabbed the certificate again

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect self-signed.badssl.com:443 < /dev/null
```

After updating the certificate in my (forked) repl, the snippet passes:
https://repl.it/repls/UnselfishAvariciousDeletions